# Автоматизация построения связей между полями таблиц на разных серверах

Tags: база-данных, sql-server, инструменты-разработчика

Дано:

1. Имеется n-ное количество одинаковых серверов БД (SQL Server) в разных точках (OLTP) (т.н. операторские БД)
2. Имеется DWH (SQL Server), в которое, с помощью различных механизмов сливаются данные из операторских БД для последующего формирования и обработки olap-кубов.

Задача:

> Описать все механизмы перелива данных (процедура, стороннее приложение, репликация, подписка etc.) из операторских БД в DWH (описать поля DWH).

Вопрос:
Как называется (или по каким ключевым словам искать) программное обеспечение, которое:

- либо автоматизирует процесс формирования описания связей
- либо облегчает труд человека, который занимается описанием этих связей?

В данный момент обычный файл-таблица, в который записывается поле из операторской БД(название, тип, размерность, значение по умолчанию, описание поля), описывается процесс, по которому оно превращается в поле в DWH и, собственно, третья колонка - название поля в DWH (название, тип, размерность, значение по умолчанию, описание поля).

*Спрашивал неоднократно у гугла на эту тему, но проблема, скорее всего, в неправильной постановке вопроса мною.*

Comment: Попробуйте отследить процессы по модификации данных на стороне DWH с помощью штатного SQL Profiler

Comment: @dzhukov, Вопрос не в способе получения информации - добыть данные из etl-процессов руками не самая сложная задача - открываем процесс и смотрим зависимости. Вопрос в автоматическом извлечении зависимостей между полями одной БД и полями другой БД, формируя в текстовом виде ETL-алгоритм. К примеру:source_table.customerId (int, NOT NULL) -> sp_transform_customer -> target_table.customerId(varchar(255), NULL).